# Add debugging symbols to objdump -d

Tags: shared-object

I have a shared object (from a Debian package) and its debug library (from the associated debug package). If I disassemble the SO with `objdump -d` I only see (what I believe to be) the exported symbols. I would like to be able to see also the other symbols that are described in the debug library. Is there any way to do that?

(in a sense I would like to "merge back" the data that was stripped during compilation)

Comment: Probably means you need to use libbfd (the lib on which binutils builds) or similar to manipulate the symbol table inside the existing shared object. Personally I'd probably write a wrapper for the lib and then use that to import, say, the map file generated by IDA.